# How to pass partial derivatives with respect to t to the integral - Heat Equation in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

The initial value problem
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{lcl}
\partial_{t}u(x,t) & = & \triangle u(x,t) + f(x,t), \ \ x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, \ t > 0; \\
u(x,0) & = & u_{0}(x), \ \ x \in \mathbb{R}^{n},
\end{array}
\right.
$$
for $u_{0}$ and $f$ in some function classes.

We know that to solve such this problem above, we must divide it into two problems and one of them is the non-homogeneous problem with null initial data
$$
(NH)\left\{
\begin{array}{lcl}
\partial_{t}u(x,t) & = & \triangle u(x,t) + f(x,t), \ \ x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, \ t > 0; \\
u(x,0) & = & 0, \ \ x \in \mathbb{R}^{n},
\end{array}
\right.
$$
I'm finding the following candidate  solution the problema (NH):
$$
u(x,t) = \int_{0}^{t}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}K(x-y,t-s)f(y,s)dyds.
$$
where
$$
K(x,t) = (4\pi t)^{-n/2}e^{-\frac{|x|^{2}}{4t}} \ \ \text{and} \ \ \partial_{t}K(x,t) = \triangle K(x,t) \ \ \text{for} \ \ (x,t) \in \mathbb{R}^{n}\times \mathbb{R}^{+}.
$$

**My problem:**

Considering functions $f(x,t)$ in several spaces, for example, $f \in C(\mathbb{R}_{0}^{+};L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n}))$ or some other space of functions (they may impose extra conditions on $f$ as they see fit). I want to show that $u$ given above is in fact a solution of (NH). **I'm having trouble justifying passing the partial derivatives with respect to $t$ into the integral.**

Comment: Have you tried [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)?

Comment: To differentiate $u(x, t) = \int_{0}^{t}u(x, t; s)\,ds$ with respect to $t$, write $g(t_1, t_2) = \int_{0}^{t_1}u(x, t_2; s)\,ds$ and apply the chain rule to compute $u_t(x, t) = \partial_t(g(t, t))$.

Comment: @Mason if I ask that the function $f$ be continuous and that its partial derivatives are non-continuous. Also, asking $f$ to have compact support, how can I ensure that I can enter the derivatives into the integral?

Comment: @Twhors For the heat equation it's true that it is difficult to verify the differentiation.  In this case I think you just have to verify directly that the function is a solution using integration by parts and intuition. The method I wrote is what motivates you to try that solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule),
\begin{multline}
\partial_t u =  \lim_{s->t^-}\left[\int_{\mathbb R^n}K(x-y, t-s)f(y,s)dy\right] + \int_0^t\int_{\mathbb R^n} \partial_tK(x-y,t-s)f(y,s)dyds \\
 = \int_{\mathbb R^n} \lim_{s->t^-}\left[K(x-y, t-s)\right]f(y,t)dy + \int_0^t\int_{\mathbb R^n}\nabla^2K(x-y, t-s)f(y,s) \\
 = \int_{\mathbb R^n} \delta(x - y)f(y,t)dy + \nabla^2\int_0^t\int_{\mathbb R^n}K(x-y, t-s)f(y,s) = f(x,t) + \nabla^2 u.
\end{multline}
Depending on how much you care about rigor, you strictly speaking need to prove that taking the limit inside the integral is valid. It does work out, though.

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: if I ask that the function $f$ be continuous and that its partial derivatives are non-continuous. Also, asking $f$ to have compact support, how can I ensure that I can enter the derivatives into the integral?